# Providing tomcat path to build.username.properties

Tags: liferay

I am using Windows 7 Operating System.

I have downloaded tomcat bundle and unzipped it inside the

```
D:\LiferayJulyServer\liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1\tomcat-7.0.23
```

so inside the `build.username.properties` file inside life ray plugin SDK

```
 app.server.type=tomcat
    app.server.dir=${project.dir}/../bundles/tomcat-6.0.26
    app.server.deploy.dir=${app.server.dir}/webapps
    app.server.lib.global.dir=${app.server.dir}/lib/ext
    app.server.portal.dir=${app.server.dir}/webapps/ROOT
```

So my question is, can I provide the absolute path of tomcat this way

```
app.server.dir=D:\LiferayJulyServer\liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1\tomcat-7.0.23
```

Or please tell me if this is not the way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide an absolute path in there, but you should use forward-slashes "/" instead of backslashes "\" as directory separators, otherwise they might be interpreted as escaping the following character. E.g. `...\tomcat` will be interpreted as `...<tab>omcat` which is a directory that does not exist.

Windows will happily work with these separators.